# Keyboard arrow navigation should not consider hidden special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

I have created an example here http://jsfiddle.net/8y36phcz/2/ to show the scenario.

In this I have a special character `dot(.)` in the HTML. In the output it is not visible. Now when I use the keyboard left and right arrow to navigate, I want to skip the `dot(.)` and go to next/previous position. Right now the `dot(.)` is not visible in the output but still the keyboard arrows keys are counting it and need two times left/right key press to move to the next position.

Is it possible to do it in such a way that the keyboard does not consider this `dot(.)` and move to the next character? Please check in Chrome.

Comment: Why do you have the dot there (I ask because maybe there's a better solution)? Also lots of garbage in your html - if this is an angular question by all means leave it there but otherwise please make it readable.

Comment: wow, ermm .... is it possible to format your HTML  ?

Comment: Its an AngularJS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put together some ideas from different posts though not very efficient. Hope its helps someone with the same problem. I have created the working example `here` http://jsfiddle.net/tjjgukLp/1/.